# Scrapy user login not working with FormRequest.from_response()

Tags: python, post, cookies, scrapy, scrapy-request

I just set up an simple Scrapy-Spider to crawl some data protected by an userlogin.
For some hours I tried to login with Scrapy `FormRequest.from_response()` into the following website by using the local signin (second one): https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/

As I can see from the console-output, the data gets POSTED to the server (see attached logfile --> REDIRECTING 302) but after this redirection, the login was not successful. I guess it has something to do with cookies, but I was not able to solve this problem.

Also attached, you will find the captured network traffic during a regular login.

For testreasons, I tried with the same code the login to http://quotes.toscrape.com/login. This worked fine!

Scrapy-Code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "meincampus3"
    start_urls = ['https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0']

    def parse(self, response):
        full_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="loginform"]/@action').extract_first()
        query = urlparse(full_url).query
        login_url = "https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?" + query
        print("fullurl: "+full_url)
        print("query: "+query)
        print("loginurl: " + login_url)

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url=login_url,
            formid='loginform',
            clickdata={'type': 'submit'},
            formdata={
                'username': 'UN',
                'password': 'PASSWD',
                'submit': 'Anmelden',
            },
            callback=self.after_login,
        )


    def after_login(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

Console-Output:

```
(env) johannesschilling@Johannes-MBP scrapytutorial % scrapy crawl meincampus3
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.2.1 started (bot: scrapytutorial)
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.10, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.7.7 (default, Jun  4 2020, 19:29:32) - [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Darwin-19.5.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'scrapytutorial',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapytutorial.spiders',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapytutorial.spiders']}
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 239396afe0083e22
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-08-04 11:29:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-08-04 11:29:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0> (referer: None)
fullurl: /qisserver/rds;jsessionid=6EA68E318E6C51D64DEFD0EA6C33417A.cit-prod-tomcat1;xuser=6DB5F329336AE359E3568D30A10EBC75.cit-prod-tomcat1?state=user&type=1
query: state=user&type=1
loginurl: https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=1
2020-08-04 11:29:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0&category=menu.browse&breadCrumbSource=&startpage=portal.vm> from <POST https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=1>
2020-08-04 11:29:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0&category=menu.browse&breadCrumbSource=&startpage=portal.vm> (referer: https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   scrapy     scrapy module (contains scrapy.Request, scrapy.Selector, etc)
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x10a1cb5d0>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0&category=menu.browse&breadCrumbSource=&startpage=portal.vm>
[s]   response   <200 https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0&category=menu.browse&breadCrumbSource=&startpage=portal.vm>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x10b1ed710>
[s]   spider     <QuotesSpider 'meincampus3' at 0x10b04cc50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
>>>
```

[Networktraffic POST-request general](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZDy.png)

[Networktraffic POST-request request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEMQF.png)

[Networktraffic POST-request Formdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TANoa.png)

Login try:

[view(response) with wrong password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGrt9.png)

[view(response) with correct password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MoOF.png)

[POST-Info from correct manual login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnODK.jpg)

[GET-Info from correct manual login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB1tm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work because I don't have a valid username or password, but it seems the url given by the from_response is different from the one we see in the network traffic. I would also specify the form (to make sure the FormRequest is looking at the correct form) and the clickdata (to make sure we simulate a click on the correct button):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

full_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="loginform"]/@action').extract_first()
query = urlparse(full_url).query
login_url = "https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?" + query
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://www.campus.uni-erlangen.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4,fr;q=0.3,it;q=0.2',
}

return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            url=login_url,
            formid='loginform',
            clickdata={'type': 'submit'},
            formdata={
                'username': 'USERNAME',
                'password': 'PASSWD',
                'submit': 'Anmelden',
            },
            callback=self.after_login,
            headers=headers
        )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I implemented the changes you suggested in my upper question. There you can find the updated console output. It seems to make one step more but it is still not logged in. What else could be wrong with my code?

Comment: Difficult to say without being able to test with a working login & password. How did you make sure you're not actually logged in?

Comment: When I inspect the response, which I get after the ˋparse()ˋ-call, with ˋview(response)ˋ it is the same loginsite like before. Unfortunally I cant‘t make you an official testaccount because this would need an immatrikulation.

Comment: Maybe some headers are missing? I edited the answer and included the headers in there, not sure if this will help though

Comment: Thanks, but this did not worked as well. I added four more pictures in my question. It seems like the login worked with scrapy but we request then maybe a wrong page? When the passwd is not correct, view(response) shows an error-message in the html file. When the passwd i correct, it shows no changes...?